# iOS Mapkit, identifying "type of business"

Tags: ios8, mapkit

I've looked through numerous answers (most were slightly outdated), and I was wondering if Apple had some sort of way to identify the type of business it queried?

From the reference guide, MKMapItem has 5 variables, none of which tell me a place is a "Thai Restaurant" or something like that.

placemark
isCurrentLocation
name
phoneNumber
url

I think its interesting how when you do a MKMapkit query on "thai", it'll give you a list of thai restaurants but thats a one way street and no where later can I take a result from the query on "thai" to verify that it is indeed a "thai" restaurant. More importantly, what I am particularly interested in is if a business is a "Thai" restaurant and a "Bar" as well, I want to be able to do a MKMapKit query on "Bar" OR "Thai" and be able to get both of those tags

I can see a solution of getting the coordinates of a business then using Google Maps API or even Yelp API and doing a search on there to get the "type of business" but that seems extremely cumbersome and inefficient.

Thanks for any advice! One of my first questions so please so easy on me =)

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look with this link : http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit

The google API will send back the name, type, location of business location near you.
It's also send icons(via image link) of business location, so you can display it on the map, which can help you which is market, which is coffeeshop...

But the "Thai Restaurant" maybe too detail so google doesn't want to show it.
Sorry about my bad english.
Hope it help.

Comment: Ive gone through that tutorial before actually. My problem isnt searching for "Thai" restaurants nearby. Read the comment i left above for vivek. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For that you should use google near by place search or place search api. you can pass thailand as place name and restaurant to type and it will return you all the restaurant in thailand.

Comment: Ive used the google place API and while i can do a simple query to search for "thai restaurant" and it will indeed show me thai restaurants in the area. More specifically my problem is, what if i search the name "Tims Thai Restaurant" (assume thats a real place!), google can help me retrieve the object for that restaurant BUT with that object alone it cannot tell me that that object is indeed a "Thai restaurant". Google places API will give me the generic information that it is a "Restaurant"

Comment: Ok so you want to specific type of Restaurant. May be four square provide it.Four square provide detailed information of object try it.

Comment: Right I know I can use yelp and foursquare to get that information. I was just hoping I wouldnt have to use multiple APIs to do something relatively so simple in my mind